# Monitors "sleep" after no external input for a period of time

Tags: windows-7, display, screensaver

After about 10 minutes my monitors will go into low-power mode (just as if I had removed the video input). If I am actively doing something I do not observe this behavior, and quick movement of the mouse or input from the keyboard will bring them back to normal.

Is there a setting I am missing that prevents this from occurring? I could not find any related settings on my monitor.

I do not observe this behavior when I am running linux.

Comment: Control Panel > All Control Panel Items> Power Options >Edit Plan Settings and change "Turn of the display" value.

Comment: I just realized this .. I don't use Windows enough I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a setting I am missing that prevents this from occurring?

Check your power settings:

- Goto "Control Panel" > "All Control Panel Items" > "Power Options"
- Click > "Change Plan Settings"
- Change "Turn of the display" value (one of the values is "Never")
- Click "Save changes"

[image]